# How are REST api "expand features" implemented in SQL (without ORM)

Tags: sql, api, orm

REST APIs often have the feature to expand nested objects in their responses. I have an API to maintain and I would like to implement this feature. I would like to hear about how the community approaches the problem when it comes to SQL.

With an ORM it is possible to expand dynamically, at runtime, but this causes extra roundtrips to the database, and with big objects, the ORM is gonna make dozens of database queries. Ideally, I would like to limit each endpoint to a single SQL query. Therefore what is the common approach?

1. Parse the URL and chose the query to execute based on the expand parameter?
2. Fetch all the data in a single query and filter out data according to the expand parameter?

What's problematic is that if I want to avoid multiple roundtrips to the database, I need to know in advance which expand combinations are possible. It is very difficult to allow deeply nested expands for instance.

Thanks